# Using Less to optimally format a 3 part row in a non-responsive web application

Tags: css, less

I am working on a web application that is not-responsive (always runs in FullHD).
In my website, I have a topbar that consists of 3 areas:

LEFT:   between 1-8 buttons
MIDDLE: An address bar (breadcrumb - alwys the widest element)
RIGHT:  one button

Currenty, I have this in my .less file:

```
.partLeft {
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
}

.partMiddle {
  width: calc(~"100% - 400px");
  float: left;
}

.partRight {
  float: right;
  min-width: 75px;
}
```

While this works ok, I suppose it could be solved much better and nicer. It would be nice if the middle would always use all the available space between the LEFT and the RIGHT.

I am using the Official LESS CSS Compiler for Java, version 1.7.0.1.1        http://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-java

Comment: You can use flex or grid to solve this and the solution using those 2 grid systems really has nothing to do with LESS. LESS is a css preprocessor, it doesn't enhance css's abilities. In some cases it will be easier to write with LESS but functionality of the css remains the the same

Comment: Sure, but in my case, this is not optional. My CSS must be generated by the LESS preprocessor.

Comment: Ok, what you have now is already LESS, pure css in a LESS file is LESS because LESS is just an enhanced way of writing css. I don't see any issues with the code itself. What exactly are you looking to do? You only have 3 items and they look fine

Comment: Thanks, I will clarify: I would like to improve the `.partMiddle` by removing the absolute number `400px`. This looks perfect when the left part contains 8 buttons (the maximum). When there are fewer buttons, the number 400 could be smaller.

Comment: Ok that's almost a different question, you should update your question to reflect that. As I mentioned in the first comment, you should look into flex or grid, I suggest you look at  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for flex, it's actually really easy to undersand

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved using basic flexbox. By adding `display: flex` to a container element and the `flex: 1` property to your "address bar" area. Floating and `calc()` is not required. The `flex` property will make the `partMiddle` element take up any remaining space between `partLeft` and `partRight`.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="partLeft">Left (Buttons)</div>
  <div class="partMiddle">Middle (Address Bar)</div>
  <div class="partRight">Right (Button)</div>
</div>
```

**CSS (LESS & Flexbox) for illustration:**

```
.container {
  display: flex;

  .partLeft, 
  .partRight {
    min-width: 75px;
  }

  .partMiddle {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

**[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erOrQg)**

A cleaner CSS version (that will work with LESS, but will ultimately generate a smaller CSS file) would be:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.partLeft, 
.partRight {
  min-width: 75px;
}

.partMiddle {
  flex: 1;
}
```

**Note:** This does also include the added benefit of being responsive, even though it is not needed by the OP.

Comment: Given the markup, there is no need to include any element in the container umbrella, this just creates extra css

Comment: @Huangism Agreed.  It was added for illustration purposes for the OP.

Comment: I think you should mention it as part of the answer so the OP does not get the wrong idea.

Comment: @Huangism Updated.  Does this make more sense to you?

Comment: A thumbs up for that